# How to create user for a db in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, authentication, connection

I have installed PostgreSQL 8.4 on my CentOS server and connected to root user from shell and accessing the PostgreSQL shell.

I created the database and user in PostgreSQL.

While trying to connect from my PHP script it shows me authentication failed.

How do I create a new user and how to grant permissions to them for a particular DB?

Comment: what exactly is the error message? can you log in through `psql` from the commandline?

Answer (score 388):

From CLI:

```
$ su - postgres 
$ psql template1
template1=# CREATE USER tester WITH PASSWORD 'test_password';
template1=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "test_database" to tester;
template1=# \q
```

PHP (as tested on localhost, it works as expected):

```
  $connString = 'port=5432 dbname=test_database user=tester password=test_password';
  $connHandler = pg_connect($connString);
  echo 'Connected to '.pg_dbname($connHandler);
```

Comment: For Ubuntu it should be `sudo su - postgres`

Comment: For Ubuntu it should really be: sudo -u postgres psql

Comment: I think the most portable way to issue the commands would be: `psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE..."`

Comment: Just remember that all the stuff you type and run in the shell usually ends up in shell history, including your chosen password.

Comment: notice difference between `'` and `"` in commands!

Comment: If you want a user named "user" you need to wrap it in double quotes like so: `CREATE USER "user" WITH PASSWORD 'password';`

Comment: If you also have to create the database,  after the `su - postgres` part do  `psql` then `CREATE DATABASE template1;`.

Comment: one-liner CLI equivalent: `createuser -P --superuser tester` (this will prompt for password)

Answer (score 52):

Create the user with a password :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html

```
CREATE USER name [ [ WITH ] option [ ... ] ]

where option can be:

      SUPERUSER | NOSUPERUSER
    | CREATEDB | NOCREATEDB
    | CREATEROLE | NOCREATEROLE
    | CREATEUSER | NOCREATEUSER
    | INHERIT | NOINHERIT
    | LOGIN | NOLOGIN
    | REPLICATION | NOREPLICATION
    | CONNECTION LIMIT connlimit
    | [ ENCRYPTED | UNENCRYPTED ] PASSWORD 'password'
    | VALID UNTIL 'timestamp'
    | IN ROLE role_name [, ...]
    | IN GROUP role_name [, ...]
    | ROLE role_name [, ...]
    | ADMIN role_name [, ...]
    | USER role_name [, ...]
    | SYSID uid
```

Then grant the user rights on a specific database :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html

Example :

```
grant all privileges on database db_name to someuser;
```

Comment: I have already done this:
create user ravi with password 'ravi';
grant all privileges on database nominatim to ravi;

But I can not connect with following PHP code:
<?php
  $connString = 'host=localhost port=5432 dbname=nominatim user=ravi password=ravi';
  $connHandler = pg_connect($connString);
  echo 'Connected to '.pg_dbname($connHandler);
?>

Comment: @Darji Krunal: what's the PHP error, how does it look like?

Comment: grant all privileges* ...