# psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, psql, ezpublish

Hi i am using postgresql .

my

```
Postgres User : postgres 
Passwprd : abc123
```

but when i type `root@xxxx:~#psql -U postgres -W`

it says

```
   root@xxxx:~#   Ident authentication failed for user "root"
```

but when i `su postgres cd` and then type following command

```
#psql -U postgres -W
```

it is working correctly and i can access to all databases .

when i try to access my site it gives me the error in posstgres error log

```
password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

why is this happening   , please help me , thanks in advance

UPDATE

my `pg_hba.conf`

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

Comment: you just create `create role root login`

Comment: @dude how can i do that ? where should i creae this ?

Comment: in pgAdmin its a sql script

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861320/3682599)

Comment: @dude superb , that worked for , me please put your comment as an answer i will mark it as crrect , thank you very very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a role name `root`

```
create role root login
```

Comment: Hi now the page is reloading again and again  , i checked the postgres error .log it says permission denied for relation ezuser
, actually it is permission denied for all relations , but when i type  SELECT contentobject_id, login, email, password_hash, password_hash_type FROM   ezuser in console it is working perfectly /