# Fedora cannot log into phppgadmin, but to psql

Tags: apache, postgresql, fedora, phppgadmin

I have fedora 21 and I want to access postgresql db using phpPgAdmin. To do it I have installed httpd and phppgadmin, postgresql too.
I can log with no problem to pgql using for example

```
psql -U learning -W template1
```

or

```
psql -W template1
```

but when I enter localhost/phpPgAdmin I cannot log in
the diff between to log in attempts in

```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "POST /phpPgAdmin/redirect.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2268 "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/redirect.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/browser.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3005 "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/themes/default/global.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/libraries/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/xloadtree/xtree2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/themes/global.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/themes/default/global.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/xloadtree/xloadtree2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/title.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/Refresh.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/Servers.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/L.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/Loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/I.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/servers.php?action=tree HTTP/1.1" 200 275 "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2015:17:44:27 +0100] "GET /phpPgAdmin/images/themes/default/DisconnectedServer.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost/phpPgAdmin/browser.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
```

my /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf is

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

my /etc/phpPgAdmin/config.inc.php

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

this is as far as I found how to make it work, but I do not how to do it
phpPgAdmin at fail log in tells me "Próba zalogowania nie powiodła się.", which probably is something like "Attemt to log in has failed" 
localhost/phpMyAdmin works normally
Can I somehow get reason why I was not logged in? Wrong password, no server etc?

SOLUTION
I have gone easy way, reinstalled fedora and now everything works, but that is actually not a solution :P

Comment: Where are you trying to access it from? Your personal computer? You said localhost works though. Did you add your IP address to the pg_hba conf?

Comment: yes personal computer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

If this is your IP address range that is accessing your computer then change

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          ident
```

to this

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          trust
```

Reload Postgres after you change it. And see if you can login.

You may also need to enable networking by changing this in the postgres conf.

from

```
listen_addresses='localhost'
```

to

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

*Also be sure you have granted all the appropriate priviliges to the user to be able to access that database or any databases your are wanting to manage.*

**Edit:**

It might be an SELinux issue. You can temporarily turn off SELinux for testing by using this command.

```
setenforce 0
```

Then test the login and see if it works. If it does work that means selinux is preventing access, you should run this command to allow httpd to continue to work after reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: where I can find listen_addresses='localhost' ?

Comment: I believe it should be in `postgresql.conf`.  and reload after changes.

Comment: found it in /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf, but already was listen_addresses='*'

Comment: It should however work with pg_hba changes I mentioned first. Are you using a new database login or the default postgres user?

Comment: Make sure you have granted all privilges to the database you are trying to access to the new user. Use postgres user to update permissions if you need to.

Comment: @up2 i do not excaptly get it. I have 3 postgresql users: mstankiewicz, learning and postgres (2 first with password) and 3 system users: mstankiewicz, postgres and root (all with password). only databases existing are default (so probably template1 ...), I tried to log in using psql with all users and always success, but via localhost/phpPgAdmin none of them access. mstankiewicz and learning are new users to my localhost postgresql server

Comment: Those users will not have access by default when there is no schema they are assigned permissions to. You will need to use postgres/root or give them access to template1 since that's the only one. You need to create a database with the user from psql and assign all privileges to it and then you'll be able to login as that user to that database with phppgadmin. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10861320/330987

Comment: I have all privileges on database template1 to mstankiewicz, no result

Comment: Do you have Selinux on e.g. enforcing?

Comment: how to check it and do it? I am linux noob actually

Comment: SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      29

Comment: Tried but does not seem to work. Maybe something in phpPgAdmin configuration? phpMyAdmin is working normally, same go for both mysql/psql programs

Comment: Did you do all of what I have up there including pg_hba conf make sure it's your IP of your pc or at least in the range listed there and turning off selinux? Make sure you have restarted postgres and restart httpd for good measure. Otherwise I don't know what else to tell you. I've pretty much covered what's typically the causes of that.

Comment: FYI I don't use phppgadmin myself, I prefer pgadmin as it's a client on the desktop. Like Heidisql is for mysql. Which works great.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same issue. It is definitely SELinux. PHP is trying to connect to the Unix stream in `/run/postgresql`. That is being blocked by `httpd_t` (which is what php-fpm is) not having `tclass=unix_stream_socket `. The solution I found was, add TCP permission, as show in the answer, *and* switch phpPgAdmin to use localhost, rather than the Unix socket. The way to do that is to edit phpPgAdmin's `conf/config.inc.php`, so that it has: `$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';` . This then worked. I would love to know what's the SELinux way to allow http_t to connect to the strea